# Symfony 1.4 - set template for component / partial

Tags: templates, symfony1, view, components, partial

I'm trying to set a different template for components/partials, but nothing works.
Here is the problem, the pattern is in another folder, not a folder module. Can I somehow set the template for a component/partial from another folder?

Answer (score 1):

If your component needs to return a specific partial which is in a different module then this works:

```
return get_partial('anotherModule/partialName', ['parameterName' => $parameterValue]);
```

Be aware of that if you used `$this->setVar('name', 'value')` then this won't be available in the partial. So you have to pass them too:

```
$this->setVar('parameterName2', 'parameterValue2');
[..]

return get_partial('anotherModule/partialName', [
    'parameterName1' => $parameterValue1,
    'parameterName2' => $this->getVar('parameterName2'),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
http://journal.lerouxdelens.com/2009/05/settemplate-in-a-sfcomponent-symfony-12/

Comment: this link is not available anymore!